# Media Player - Play/Pause, Volume, Expand Controls Missing

Tags: controls, media-player, mediaelement.js

I recently downloaded and installed the `Yootheme WidgetKit Media Player`, which uses MediaElement.js, to my Joomla Yootheme Master Theme.  Unfortunately, I am running into a small problem.  When I go into the Widgetkit and click `"enable javascript"` the controls (play/pause, volume, expand to fullscreen) disappear.  If I click on `"disable javascript"` the controls appear, but the player no longer properly fits tablets and mobile devices (even if I set `width="100%"` or `class="size-auto"`).

The widgetkit was designed to work JavaScript enabled.  Now I have made sure mime type is set up for svg images and I have checked all the system requirements.  I have verified that JavaScript works on my site.  I also searched and did not find any jQuery errors (no multiple jQuery requests).

I am completely confused at this point.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

in your .htaccess file add the following two lines. that worked for me

AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz

AddEncoding gzip svgz